# Popup position to Bottom-Right

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ToggleButton which when clicked, sets the `IsActionMenuOpen` to true so that the popup can be displayed. What my desired outcome would be that the placement for the popup would be to the bottom right like [here](http://img1.imagilive.com/0311/combo_right.png). Any ideas on how to do this? Also, if the window is being resized, can a solution be found so that the popup will move as well?

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="PART_TGAction">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_SubjectActions"  
                                        Text="Actions" 
                                        Margin="4,0,0,0" 
                                              PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="PART_SubjectActions_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                        />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsActionMenuOpen, Mode=OneWay}" 
                             x:Name="PART_Popup">
                        <Border Background="White">
                            ......
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by placing it in the Loaded event of the UserControl:

```
PART_Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback += (Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset) => new[] { new CustomPopupPlacement() { Point = new Point(targetSize.Width - popupSize.Width, targetSize.Height) } };
```

Comment: NB : don't forget to set Placement="Custom" on your Popup object for this to work (had me puzzled for a while before figuring this out)